# jQuery Ajax How Do I Pass responseText as variable to indexOf?

Tags: jquery, indexof, responsetext

I am trying to append a p element from the responseText of an Ajax request.

Before appending, I would like to see if the responseText already exists in the parent div element text, and not add it if that is the case.  The problem is I cannot get indexOf(responseText) to work using the variable responseText.  My code works when I pass a string literal to indexOf.

Here is my code:

```
jQuery('#addButton').live('click', function () {

    new Ajax('<url>', {
        method: 'get',
        dataType: 'html',
        onSuccess: function (responseText) {
            var text = jQuery('#div').text();

            if (text.indexOf(responseText) == -1) {
                //always true using responseText; 
                //string literal works though
                jQuery('#div').append(responseText);
            }
        }
    }).request();

})
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: what does `responseText` and the text of `#div` look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the response with jQuery and try the comparison with the `text()` representation of it...

```
var resp = $(responseText);
var div = $("#div");

if(div.text().indexOf(resp.text()) == -1)
  resp.appendTo(div)
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe because you're looking for html within plain text. Try using `html` instead of `text`:

```
var text = jQuery('#div').html();
if (text.indexOf(responseText) == -1) {
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

No solutions above were working for me (jQuery 1.11.2).

But I found finally my solution: `$(my_variable).selector`

It works without problem for me :

```js
var responseText = "word";
var resp = $(responseText).selector;



$("div").each(function() {
  if ($(this).text().indexOf(resp) >= 0) {
    alert("I've found your query: " + resp + " at " + $(this).offset().left + "/" + $(this).offset().top);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>THis is a test</div>
<div>I'm searching for this word</div>
<div>nothing here</div>
```